# OR in SQL giving problems

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * 
    FROM FEEDER A
    WHERE A.CF = 'X'
    OR A.SF = 'X'
    AND A.YEAR = 2021;
```

When I run the above query, it brings back all the years ! I only want 2021 where CF OR SF is X.

Comment: AND goes before OR.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need 2 Parenthesis -

```
SELECT * 
    FROM FEEDER A
    WHERE (A.CF = 'X'
    OR A.SF = 'X')
    AND A.YEAR = 2021;
```

Or can shorten your query to -

```
SELECT * 
    FROM FEEDER A
    WHERE 'X' IN (A.CF, A.SF)
    AND A.YEAR = 2021;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` operator has higher precedence than the `OR` operator so your query is the same as:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   FEEDER A
WHERE  (A.CF = 'X')
OR     (A.SF = 'X' AND A.YEAR = 2021);
```

and will return: any year where `CF = 'X'`; or only the 2021 year when `SF = 'X'`.

---

If you want to fix your query then you need either:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   FEEDER A
WHERE  A.CF = 'X'
AND    A.YEAR = 2021
OR     A.SF = 'X'
AND    A.YEAR = 2021;
```

or, slightly easier to read, use brackets:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   FEEDER A
WHERE  (  A.CF = 'X'
       OR A.SF = 'X')
AND    A.YEAR = 2021;
```

or, use the `IN` operator:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   FEEDER A
WHERE  'X' IN (A.CF, A.SF)
AND    A.YEAR = 2021;
```